# How do I install uTorrent on 12.04?

Tags: installation, utorrent

I have just install Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to install uTorrent. It's was easy on Windows. As you can see on the [official web-site](http://www.utorrent.com/help/faq), there is no GUI version for Linux.

> So how can I install **uTorrent** on ubuntu 12.04

**NOTE:** if I have to use command line(Terminal) for it, please tell me how to open it.

Thanks.

Comment: Open the terminal by using CTRL + ALT + T

Comment: I recommend that you use transmission. Transmission is a lightweight BitTorrent client, that works great, and it comes included with Ubuntu. I personally like it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install uTorrent on Ubuntu 12.04, you can try it on either of the following. (Wine based methods)

- PlayOnLinux (POL)
- Winetricks

You can install uTorrent by following the blow procedure. But, i recommend to use buil-in torrent client like `Vuze` in 12.04.

**METHOD 1: (PlayOnLinux)**

If you have executable of uTorrent, ie; uTorrent.exe, it is better to try POL.

POL installation:-
Run the command in a terminal:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Click on the install button, after running the POL. Then click on the link below the POL install menu window:

> Install a non-listed program

Then follow the procedure as you install `uTorrent` on Windows.

**METHOD 2: (Winetricks)**

This can be used if you don't have any uTorrent.exe files.

First install Winetricks using:

`sudo apt-get install winetricks`.

Then try : `winetricks utorrent`.

(Or manually go to Winetricks GUI and select "Install an app-->uTorrent-->OK)

It will show otput as:

```
Executing w_do_call utorrent
Executing load_utorrent
------------------------------------------------------
Please download utorrent_2.2.1.exe from http://www.oldapps.com/utorrent.php?old_utorrent=38, place it in /home/myname/.cache/winetricks/utorrent, then re-run this script.
------------------------------------------------------
```

So, go to the link  [uTorrent download](http://www.oldapps.com/utorrent.php?old_utorrent=38)  and download uTorrent.exe and place it in the specified folder "/home/myname/.cache/winetricks/utorrent".

That's it. In any of the above you can enjoy `uTorrent` in 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I recommend qBitTorrent. It can be found in the Ubuntu Software Center. It's very similar to uTorrent and is extremely easy to install and use.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question asked here? The OP is not asking for alternatives. Please post this as a comment to the question istead, I'd say.

Comment: He want's the linux equivalent of uTorrent, which qBitTorrent pretty much is. I'd say this is the correct answer.